# can I get a traceability of which user responded to whom using the Youtube API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

good day,

is it possible to know in the youtube comments, which user responded to whom? I see that when replying to a comment an automatic tag is created but the user can delete it, I attach an image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qywq6.png)

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet,replies&videoId=VIDEO_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY returns correctly `@gisec3576 MY RESPONSE` for both `textOriginal` and `textDisplay`, right?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison : And what happens if the user deletes the "@gisec3576" ? is that information lost?

Comment: As far as I know, yes this information is lost.